# Durability of HDMI versus Mini DisplayPort socket

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I want to connect second display to my 13 inch MacBook pro, which will be connected and disconnected 2 times a day on average.

Is it better to use HDMI or Mini DisplayPort as far as durability of the socket is concerned?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a non-pro Aluminium unibody Macbook (2008), the first one with mini display port. It's 6.5 years old, and I've been using external display for 4 years. I unplug it once a week only, and its failing for more than a year, maybe 2 years: it is getting loosy day after day, showing artifacts or non working. You need to move the cable to get it working again. And the adaptor is official...
Maybe now they make it stronger...

Comment: How does it feel today?

Comment: It is still my only computer, and it still works well. It seems the problem was actually related with the mini display port to DVI (official) adaptor, and not with the laptop's socket.

Answer (score 1):

I would not really be worried about the durability of the sockets.
Both should be durable.

However, I suggest you to use Thunderbolt as I guess you have 2 of them on you MacBook pro ;)

Comment: I would also choose to use an Apple-branded cable instead of a third-party.